# Should I use document fragment in JS in 2019

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning DOM manipulation and then I came across document fragment allowing put multiple elements inside another node element in the dom in an efficient way. But as the benchmark depicts in here:https://jsperf.com/out-of-dom-vs-documentfragment/3, document fragment is not so fast compared to not using document fragment does it mean that document fragment is not so useful?

Comment: I think you are drawing a wrong conclusion. For some "documentfragment" is slightly faster, for same "out of dom" is slightly faster. Generally, the difference is negligible.

Comment: @str, you think they are pretty relevant even if being not so efficient compared to out od dom?

Comment: How can you say "not so efficient compared [...]"? There is no clear winner.  For some "documentfragment" is slightly faster, for some "out of dom" is slightly faster.